# Fill NaN with mean of a group for each column

Tags: python, pandas

I Know that the `fillna()` method can be used to fill NaN in whole dataframe.

```
df.fillna(df.mean()) # fill with mean of column.
```

How to limit mean calculation to the group (and the column) where the NaN is.

**Exemple:**

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np 

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'a': pd.Series([1,1,1,2,2,2]),
    'b': pd.Series([1,2,np.NaN,1,np.NaN,4])
})

print df
```

**Input**

```
   a   b
0  1   1
1  1   2
2  1 NaN
3  2   1
4  2 NaN
5  2   4
```

**Output** (after groupby('a') & replace NaN by mean of group)

```
   a    b
0  1  1.0
1  1  2.0
2  1  1.5
3  2  1.0
4  2  2.5
5  2  4.0
```

Comment: Sorry are you asking specifically for output here?

Comment: this output is just an exemple, but say you have many NaNs in different other columns b, c, d, etc...

Comment: In the future it would be useful to post your complete requirements as it matters and it affects the answers

Answer (score 6, accepted):

IIUC then you can call [`fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.fillna.html) with the result of [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.groupby.html) on 'a' and [`transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#transformation) on 'b':

```
In [44]:
df['b'] = df['b'].fillna(df.groupby('a')['b'].transform('mean'))
df

Out[44]:
   a    b
0  1  1.0
1  1  2.0
2  1  1.5
3  2  1.0
4  2  2.5
5  2  4.0
```

If you have multiple `NaN` values then I think the following should work:

```
In [47]:
df.fillna(df.groupby('a').transform('mean'))

Out[47]:
   a    b
0  1  1.0
1  1  2.0
2  1  1.5
3  2  1.0
4  2  2.5
5  2  4.0
```

**EDIT**

```
In [49]:
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'a': pd.Series([1,1,1,2,2,2]),
    'b': pd.Series([1,2,np.NaN,1,np.NaN,4]),
    'c': pd.Series([1,np.NaN,np.NaN,1,np.NaN,4]),
    'd': pd.Series([np.NaN,np.NaN,np.NaN,1,np.NaN,4])
})
df

Out[49]:
   a   b   c   d
0  1   1   1 NaN
1  1   2 NaN NaN
2  1 NaN NaN NaN
3  2   1   1   1
4  2 NaN NaN NaN
5  2   4   4   4

In [50]:
df.fillna(df.groupby('a').transform('mean'))

Out[50]:
   a    b    c    d
0  1  1.0  1.0  NaN
1  1  2.0  1.0  NaN
2  1  1.5  1.0  NaN
3  2  1.0  1.0  1.0
4  2  2.5  2.5  2.5
5  2  4.0  4.0  4.0
```

You get all `NaN` for 'd' as all values are `NaN` for group `1` for `d`

Comment: The answer on your edit, is what i'm looking for. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

We first compute the group means, ignoring the missing values:

```
group_means = df.groupby('a')['b'].agg(lambda v: np.nanmean(v))
```

Next, we use `groupby` again, this time fetching the corresponding values:

```
df_new = df.groupby('a').apply(lambda t: t.fillna(group_means.loc[t['a'].iloc[0]]))
```